# How to check if the column value are the same among multiple record with one sql

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose there is a table

```
id      desc
1        a
1        b
1        c
1        a
2        a
2        a
```

what I want to do is to show a mix of desc if the desc under the same id are different, otherswise show the value of the desc. Just like below

```
id     desc
1      a/b/c
2      a
```

How could I do it in one sql ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `group_concat()` with the `distinct` modifier:

```
select id, group_concat(distinct `desc` separator '/') as `desc`
from t
group by id;
```

Note that `desc` is a bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword (think `order by`).  It is best to avoid grammatical elements when choosing names.